# How can add metabox for post of specific category before save post and after save post

Tags: posts, metabox

I want to add Metabox for the posts of category=5 and i am using the following code but unable to do so . So please help me out->

```
add_action('admin_init','my_meta_init');

function my_meta_init()
{
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

    // checks for post/page ID
    //if ($post_id->post_category[0] == 5)
    if ( $post_id && in_category( 5, $post_id ) )
    {
        add_meta_box('team_meta', 'My Custom Meta Box 1', 'team_meta', 'post', 'normal', 'high');


    function team_meta_1(){
    global $post;
    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the location data if its already been entered
    $designation = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_designation', true);

    // Echo out the field
    echo '<textarea name=_designation rows="6" cols="100">'.$designation.'</textarea>';
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        (function ($) {
            $('#in-category-5').change(function () {alert()}).change();
        })(jQuery);
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    }

    function my_meta_save($post_id, $post) {

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }

    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

    $events_meta['_designation'] = $_POST['_designation'];


    // Add values of $events_meta as custom fields

    foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }

}

 add_action('save_post','my_meta_save', 10, 2);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remember that because you are basing this on category IDs, you will need to save the post under category '5' before the box will appear. When I tested your code the meta box did appear after I saved the post, but you had an error.

```
add_meta_box('team_meta', 'My Custom Meta Box 1', 'team_meta', 'post', 'normal', 'high');
```

This line should actually be like this, as your function title is a little different:

```
add_meta_box('team_meta', 'My Custom Meta Box 1', 'team_meta_1', 'post', 'normal', 'high');
```

The third parameter is your callback function, which you have named 'team_meta_1'. After changing this the textarea appeared and saved correctly for me.

Comment: yes i do that now but not show me any thing. then i need this custom to show before save post how can do that

Comment: The only way to make it show up before publishing is to remove the line of PHP code that checks which category the post belongs to. This will let the box appear on all posts and you can simply only fill it out for Category 5 posts. Or, you can perhaps setup a javascript code to appear/disappear when that category option is toggled.

Comment: how can do that ??